# How to downgrade NumPy version in Spyder

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently working with Tensorflows, and it requires a lower version of NumPy to work properly because it is showing `NotImplementedError`. I am using Spyder and have Anaconda also installed on the system. So how do I downgrade the numpy version to 1.19.X? Also, since I have both Spyder and anaconda installed, it asks for using the Conda installation code.

Comment: Have you tried ``conda install numpy=1.19.X``?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not tech support.

Comment: Why `machine-learning`, `data-science` and `tensorflow` tag?

Comment: The installation code question seems separate, and should probably be removed. We prefer exactly one question per question, please.